# I want to create a countdown from 50 down to 1, but I don't want to count down the same amount of time between each number

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a countdown from 50 down to 1, but I don't want to count down the same amount of time between each number.. like if this were 50 seconds, I don't want it to count down a number every second.  I'm trying to create a countdown with a bit of randomness to it so maybe it takes 2 secs to get to the next number or sometimes .5 seconds.  I'm trying to do this all the way down to the last 10 seconds where it will slow down a bit more before the counter stops at the number 1.

Heres the HTML I have:

```
<span id="count">50</span>
```

The Javascript:

```
sec = 50;

interval = setInterval(function () {
  sec--;
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = sec;

  if (sec == 1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

}, 1000);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aVrPG/

how do I get it to slow down the last 10 seconds and how do I add a bit of randomness to it?

Comment: @JamesMontagne removed jquery tag

Comment: If you want to vary the delay between your countdown being updated, then you'll want to use `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var sec = 50;

function execute() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = sec;
}

(function loop() {
  if(sec-- == 0) {
    return // stop when we reach 0
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    execute();
    loop() 
  }, Math.round(Math.random() * 1E3) + (sec <= 10 ? 2E3 : 500))
                // random 1000 or 0  +  2000 if sec <=10 or 500 otherwise
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as changing the interval timespan you can't do that with setInterval.  You'll need to use setTimeout.

```
sec = 50;

function interval(timespan){
    setTimeout(function () {
      sec--;
      document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = sec;
        if (sec > 10){
            interval(1500);
        }
      if (sec > 1) {
        interval(1000);
  }

    }, timespan); 
}
interval(1000)
```

I'm not sure where you're wanting the randomness.  But this should point you in the right direction. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aVrPG/3/)

Comment: @bluetoft this is very close to what I want!  by randomness I mean the time between each number, not skipping any numbers but the time to get from say 41 to 42 being different from 41 to 40..  what do I change to  alter this?

Comment: @bluesoft I also noticed it goes past the number 1, how do I stop it there?

Answer (score -1):

You have to vary the Interval time. Create a new variable and asign a random value between...hm, 500 and 2000? And at least to slow down the speed at the last 10 "seconds".
Just use an if-clause.

Try this

```
sec = 50;

interval = setInterval(function () {
 sec--;
 document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = sec;

  if (sec == 1) {
   clearInterval(interval);
  }

}, (sec < 11) ? Math.floor(Math.random()*1000 + 500): Math.floor(Math.random()*1000 + 1500) );
```

Didn't test this
**edit**: Well, it works good for me.